# How do you include the Update Manager window in ALT TAB switcher in Unity7

Tags: 16.04, unity, 18.04, shortcut-keys

I love Unity7 and will probably continue to use it for a long time. One thing I'd like to change though is that the Update Manager is not included in ALT-TAB switching when launched automatically (== updates are available and the window is open by the system, not the user). Is there a way to configure that, or should I open a bug report? (Problem present in 16.04 and 18.04)